# Deprecation warning with STI model_name workaround

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sti

In my Single Table Inheritance models, I am overriding the `inherited` method in the base model so that all descendent models are recognized by the base model's name. The following code is used to add an override to the model_name method for all inherited classes.

```
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval do
      def model_name
        BaesModelDefinition.model_name
      end
    end
  end
```

I've noticed that this is producing deprecation warnings in Rails 3.2.3:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like something (probably a gem/plugin) is overriding 
the ActiveRecord::Base.inherited method. It is important that this hook executes so 
that your models are set up correctly. A workaround has been added to stop this 
causing an error in 3.2, but future versions will simply not work if the hook is
overridden.
```

Is there another approach I can use to fix the model_name issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple. Just add a `super` to the overriding method.

```
  def self.inherited(child)
    child.instance_eval do
      def model_name
        BaesModelDefinition.model_name
      end
    end
    super
  end
```

Comment: `super` will pass params by default